# Invoking Azure Function HTTP POST sending OPTIONS request first

Tags: angular, azure, azure-functions

I've an Azure Function hosted directly on Azure Infrastructure. While developing web frontend locally and deploying it on other domain, am facing a strange issue where Angular is sending OPTIONS request before POST request.

To resolve this, I did enabled CORS for all locations ("*"). Still, I see OPTIONS request going first. Any pointers on how to disable that?

Here is the Angular code causing problem:

```
    var headers = new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    });

    headers.delete('Cache-Control');
    headers.delete('Pragma');
    headers.delete('If-Modified-Since');
    headers.delete('X-Content-Type-Options');

    headers.append('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    headers.append('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    headers.append('If-Modified-Since', '0');
    headers.append('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');

    return this.http.post(
        this.postUrl,
        ('{"email": "' + email + '", "password": "' + encryptedPassword + '"}'),
        {
            headers: headers
        }
    ).map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: That's how CORS works. It sends OPTIONS request before actual request to check if the request it's going to send is allowed. See [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests).

Comment: According to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664909/how-to-make-a-post-request-to-azure-function-using-angular-4, I should not have OPTIONS request going out, but I still see that. That's the problem as am not able to wait on the actual result.

Comment: The linked question is about incorrect configuration of the server. App was sending `OPTIONS` requests, but server was responding with 400 code to them. Please read the link I provided, it explains what are preflight requests, why they are sent and how they work. Again, the behavior you observe is correct.